# Does import call __new__ static method?

Tags: python, class, metaclass

I know that `__new__` method is called when attempt to create an instance of a class before `__init__` is called.

But i happened to find that, import a module withou create instance will also call `__new__`

suppose i have this:

a.py:

```
import abc
class A(abc.ABCMeta):
        def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
            print("ttt:", cls, name, bases, namespace)
            retval = abc.ABCMeta.__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)
            return retval


    class B(object):
        __metaclass__ = A
```

and

b.py

```
import a

class C(B):
   def a():
      pass
```

Then i execute `python b.py`, i can see two `ttt` print by `__new__`.
So, when does the **new** exactly called, in this case, i never create any instance of the three classes i defined

Comment: Side-note: `__new__` is not a static method. It's the constructor, which implicitly behaves like a class method (it receives the class as its first argument, not an instance of the class), but it's not static; static would imply it was merely namespaced by the class, and not otherwise associated with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a metaclass to define a class, the metaclass is "called" implicitly (which invokes `__new__` since the metaclass here is an actual class), see [Invoking the metaclass](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/). I can't say why you see three prints here (you only have two classes that uses `A` as a metaclass, directly or indirectly through inheritance), but that explains two of the `print`s.

Comment: sorry for mistake, i have two prints, one for B, on for C

Comment: @demonguy: Well, you didn't accurately convey the definition of `C` (`class(C):` is invalid syntax); if it also involves using `A` as a metaclass, that would explain it.